# LINQ: How to filter list based on values from array

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, split

I would like to filter array of users, based on that if roles that exists in array are already contained in user roles list.

Here is my code which won't compile:

```
var roles = role.Split(','); // admin, basic, super-admin

listOfUsers = listOfUsers.Where(user => user.Roles.Contains(roles.Select(x => x)).ToList();
```

I want to do if admin and basic are contained in `roles` which is array of string to return only those users which have the same value in `Roles` array. (Roles is also list of strings) but this reproduces an error:

[image]

Comment: can you add more code? what's the type of `listOfUsers`, etc? what type is `user.Roles`?

Comment: Are you looking for users that have ALL roles specified in `roles`, or users that have ANY role in `roles`?

Comment: @DavidFox It states that `Roles` is also a `List<string>`

Comment: @RufusL For users that have any roles specified in roles.. Yes `Roles` is also a `List<string>`

Comment: Assuming that `user.Roles` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, then `user.Roles.Contains(roles.Select(x => x))` expects a `string` as a parameter.  We know that `roles` is a `string[]` (assuming that `role` is a string containing stuff separated by commas).  Then, `roles.Select(x=>x)` is an `IEnumerable<string>` not the `string` the function expects. This would be much easier if you gave us more code (as suggested by @DavidFox) and if your variable names weren't `role`, `roles` and `Roles`

Comment: Please post actual text for error messages. Bitmaps are not searchable, and for some people are also not even readable at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a match in one list of strings from another, you can check if `Any` user roles are contained in the `roles` list:

```
listOfUsers = listOfUsers.Where(user => user.Roles.Any(roles.Contains)).ToList();
```

If you want to do a case-insensitive comparison, you can pass a comparer to the `Contains` method:

```
listOfUsers = listOfUsers
    .Where(user => 
        user.Roles.Any(role => roles.Contains(role, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .ToList();
```